# angularjs, add loop property to video

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Probably missing something simple here but how do I add the 'loop' property to a video in my directive?

I've a variable `videoLoop` which is two way bound to the directive:

`<video class="x-video" ng-src="{{vm.videoSrc}}" autoplay {{vm.videoLoop}}></video>`

Where `vm.videoLoop` is equal to `loop`. This doesn't interpolate though.

I've also tried:

`<video class="x-video" ng-src="{{vm.videoSrc}}" autoplay loop="{{vm.videoLoop}}"></video>`

Where `vm.videoLoop` is equal to false. If I do this the attribute evaluates  to true and it continues looping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `vm.videoLoop` evaluates to `true/false` so the result will be:

```
<video class="x-video" ..... loop="true/false"></video>
```

The value of the attribute `loop` doesn't matter, `video` tag only need `loop` attribute to be present to activate looping.

For example, all the bellow `video` tags activate looping:

```
<video loop> <video loop="true"> <video loop="false">  <video loop="x">
```

To achieve your goal please try this:

```
<video class="x-video" ng-src="{{vm.videoSrc}}" autoplay ng-attr-loop="{{vm.videoLoop  || undefined}}"></video>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Another update ! short solution without the need to change much in your code !

Comment: This looks close but the {{vm.videoLoop ? "loop" : ""}} is not parsed for me when it is inside a tag like this? It works fine outside of the video tag.

Comment: @userqwert This works thanks to [ng-attr](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with property binding. Try
 `[loop] = 'vm.videoLoo'`

Comment: That's angular 2 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<video class="x-video" ng-src="{{vm.videoSrc}}" autoplay {{vm.videoLoop}}></video>
```

What I would do:

```
vm.videoloop = "loop" //when I want the video to play continuously
vm.videoloop = "" //when I want the video to play just once
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The code isn't interpolated so it just shows {{vm.videoLoop}} rather than the bound value of 'loop'